# pip: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement in WSL

Tags: pip, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to install requirements from a requirements.txt within the virtual environment on my ubuntu subsystem on Windows 10, using the following command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, for each requirement, I receive an error stating:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==4.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 
1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20, 1.11.21, 1.11.22, 1.11.23, 1.11.24, 1.11.25, 1.11.26, 1.11.27, 1.11.28, 1.11.29)
No matching distribution found for Django==4.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

I am using python 3.6 and pip 21.3.1.
I've tried updating apt, python, and pip but nothing resolved the issue.
Also installing the packages outside the venv and manually without the requirements.txt only installs them in the latest version listed in the error message (e.g. Django 1.11.29) which for almost every package is deprecated.

Do I have to update the package list or repositories of pip in any way? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of packages suggests you're using Python 2.7. You could have Python 3.6 but your `pip` runs under Python 2.7. Check with `pip --version`.

Try `pip3 install Django` or `python3.6 -m pip install Django`.

Comment: `pip --version` prints `pip 21.3.1 from pathToVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`

Comment: `python3.6 -m pip install django` installed django-3.2.13 which is still not the required version 4.0.4 :/

Comment: @Tanne https://pypi.org/project/Django/4.0/ Requires: **Python >=3.8**

Comment: I'm still confused why pip with python version 3.6 installed packages with python 2.7 but using pyton3.8 -m pip worked. Thank you.